# Sum of series : $\sum_{n=0}^∞ = \frac{1}{(n+1)2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Question asks find the sum of the series.

Firstly i tried to use geometric series formula to calculate sum but could not convert it to geo form.
$$ ar^{n-1} $$
So should we transform equation into geo form or use another method to calculate sum?

This is the equation i try to calculate sum.

$$\sum_{n=0}^∞ = \frac{1}{(n+1)2^n}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has $$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{x^n}{n+1}=\frac{1}{x} \int \left(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} x^{n}\right) dx = \frac{1}{x} \int \frac{1}{1-x} dx = -\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x},$$ for $x \in (0,1).$ Now plug $x=1/2.$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

At $ (-1,1) \; $ , the antiderivative of
$$F(a)=1+a+a^2+a^3+... +a^n+....$$

is

$$G(a)=a+\frac{a^2}{2}+...a\frac{a^n}{n+1}+...$$

Answer (score 0):

The Taylor development of $\log(1-x)$ is known to have coefficients which are minus inverses of the degrees.

Hence

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac2{(n+1)2^{n+1}}=-2\log\frac12.$$